# Display SVG in UWP app image control, desktop and phone

Tags: c#, svg, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Is there a way to display an SVG image (from a URL) in a xaml Image control in a UWP app

e.g.

```
<Image Source={Binding image_source}>
```

Where `image_source` is an absolute path to an image. Where the image is either **png** or **svg** format.

My solution works as expected with any common graphics format (jpg, png, gif) but displays nothing when the graphic is svg format.

I've seen loads of articles about converting the svg to something else, but the information comes from a web service that is not mine and use by others I would suspect. changing images on mass to png or something else I doubt would be an option.

In my application the Image is within a listView.

I've seen articles about converters and built in support for svg but none of them seem to work. I have yet to find any article here or anywhere with someone that has a working solution other than manually converting files (not an option)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://igrali.com/2015/12/24/how-to-render-svg-in-xaml-windows-10-uwp/ Or with [this](https://lasithapetthawadu.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/using-vector-svg-graphics-in-c-net/) i think you can convert .svg to a bitmap which can be displayed easily in UWP

Comment: I marked up @Hannes comment because that may be a good fix.  I personally would prefer to just use the image.Source = just like always and it work. (That answer may do that but the examples didn't show it would).  Here's my suggestion.  Make a custom image control that works just like image with a Source dependency property.  Just check the source for svg type and display the XAML (easy enough to convert) or display an image with the source.  That way on the interface when using it there's no difference in that and a typical image.

Comment: SvgImageSource is a new feature in the Creators Update https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource . For earlier versions you'll need to convert it or display in a WebView

Answer (score 1):

UWP supports SVG natively and your solution should work. I guess the issue in your case is due to scaling. Make sure your graphics image has not scaled out of boundaries and you only see transparent part of it. You might try testing other SVG files to confirm that and play with size and SVG ViewBox attribute.